# Send message to websocket-rails by curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, websocket

I uses this gem https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails. And
I try create new user in websocket-rails app by curls. For example:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/websocket -d 'message={"channel":"/new_user", "user_name":"user1"}'

http://localhost:3000/websocket_rails

http://localhost:3000/faye

http://localhost:3000/
```

But i always receive error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/websocket_rails"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/websocket"):
```

etc...

rake routes:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern             Controller#Action
public_index GET /public/index(.:format) public#index
        root GET /                       public#index
   websocket GET /websocket(.:format)    websocket_rails
```

routes.rb

```
Ws42::Application.routes.draw do
  get "public/index"
  root to: "public#index"
end
```

Which address i must write after `http://localhost:3000/` ?

Comment: Please include your routes.rb file or the result of `rake routes`

Comment: Done. And now i see that /websocket receive GET method, but curl send POST method. Hmm, can a send my data by GET method?